# Okay for electrical receptacle and sump pump discharge to be near each other?

Tags: electrical, plumbing, safety, sump-pump

We're having an additional sump and pump installed and its discharge has limited options. One of the best discharge options (shortest run to a reasonable place to leave the basement) is already an almost 40' run. Right around that spot is where we planned to add an electric receptacle for a chest freezer (we planned the pump and freezer to be on dedicated GFCI-breaker protected circuits but not with GFCI receptacles to avoid nuisance trips).
**Is there anything we should avoid in locating the sump pump discharge and the freezer receptacle?** For example, if the discharge line is 12in. left a window near the top of a concrete block foundation, is it okay to have a receptacle below that within 0-18" left of the same window?

It seems to me there's a risk of water down that wall if something went wrong with the discharge line, so the receptacle shouldn't be directly under the discharge line, but how far apart do they need to be horizontally and vertically?

Note that the pump discharge is probably coming from ground-level (buried in a French drain because of busyness at the floor joists/basement wall), while the electric circuit is coming from above run along the joists. Not sure if it helps or hurts to run the sump discharge along the joists - it would travel above our well water treatment systems and other receptacles, and it seems like keeping the discharge line below electrical is a good rule to aim for. On the other hand, the joists by the basement wall have plumbing and electrical (including GFCI receptacles) all near each other.